# Visual Studio: Find .CPP file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, explorer

How do i find a .h or .cpp file on the Solution Explorer? 
When i look for a file's name it opens for editing. I want to find where does it reside in my solution explorer.

Comment: Could you clarify this. Is it an open file you want to find in the solution explorer?

Comment: Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General > tick the "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer" checkbox.  You'll now never have to look for it when you opened the file for editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to see the directory of the residing files. If you have a similar situation like I shown in the below image:

[image]

Then you should click on the link which I highlighted and it will show you the directory structure in your solution explorer. Try it...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Shift + Alt + L` will reveal a open file in the Solution Explorer. Also if you right click on a folder in the solution explorer you can select `Open folder in file explorer`.